# $G/S$ is torsion-free?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

There is a well-known theorem that:

> If $S\le G$ and $\frac{G}{S}$ is torsion-free, so $S$ is pure in $G$.

Please hint me about the reverse. If $S$ is pure in $G$, then will $\frac{G}{S}$ is necessarily torsion-free group? Thanks.

Comment: This link could be useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_subgroup

Comment: Am I right if I say that your question is equivalent to ask for a pure subgroup $S$ which does not contain the whole torsion of the original group $G$? If this is the case a negative answer could be deduced from this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18719/example-of-intersection-of-pure-subgroup-which-is-not-pure . Please let me know if I'm just saying a pack of rubbish or not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure subgroups are limits of direct summands. In particular every direct summand is pure. Take $G$ of order 2, and $S$ of order 1 for a minimal counter example.

Comment: Thanks for the counter example. What about $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$?

Comment: For $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ the only pure subgroups are the direct summands, such as $\mathbb{Z}[\tfrac12]/\mathbb{Z}$, but they all have torsion quotients.